# Looking for a USB A/B Box

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, peripherals, splitter

I have a laptop and a tower, and I usually like to use the laptop for my chat and other miscellaneous tasks while the tower is doing the hard work during video editing projects and such.  Due to the way my desk is set up, it's kind of a stretch to reach over to the laptop's keyboard all the time, and having a second keyboard/mouse is rather cumbersome, albeit manageable if I keep the second keyboard in my lap.  Does anyone make an A/B box that I can plug into the tower and the laptop so I can just flip the keyboard over to the appropriate machine as needed?

Comment: you want to use the tower's keyboard & mouse to control the laptop, right?  a KVM switch might do it, or just install Synergy -- no switch needed, Synergy does it with TCP/IP.  http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty, google for "USB selector", here is one example
[USB 2.0 KVM 2 Port Ports Selector VGA Print Switch Box](http://www.sourcingmap.com/usb-kvm-port-ports-selector-vga-print-switch-box-p-17509.html)

But I think you really should use [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) instead.

> Synergy lets you easily share a single
>   mouse and keyboard between multiple
>   computers with different operating
>   systems, each with its own display,
>   without special hardware. It's
>   intended for users with multiple
>   computers on their desk since each
>   system uses its own monitor(s).
>
> Redirecting the mouse and keyboard is
>   as simple as moving the mouse off the
>   edge of your screen. Synergy also
>   merges the clipboards of all the
>   systems into one, allowing
>   cut-and-paste between systems.
>   Furthermore, it synchronizes screen
>   savers so they all start and stop
>   together and, if screen locking is
>   enabled, only one screen requires a
>   password to unlock them all.